# How to secure our own webservices with Amazon Cognito?

Tags: java, android, web-services, amazon-web-services, amazon-cognito

If have successfully developed and used Developer Authentication with Amazon Cognito. I have tried to upload images to S3 and download and display from there. What I want to do now is to secure my own webservice with the Cognito API.

This is how Amazon WebServices are used, e.g.

```
AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentialsProvider);
```

I want to secure my personal web services with the Cognito Security. Is it possible to secure developers personal webservices using Amazon Cognito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cognito is a mechanism for acquring AWS credentials to access AWS services. Currently there is nothing in Cognito that would allow you to secure your own API. This is a request we have heard from other customers and will certainly take it into account as we plan out our feature roadmap.

**Update 2015-07-09** AWS has announced [Amazon API Gateway](http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/). Using API Gateway you can build a REST interface to your existing API (or to AWS Lamdba functions) secured with credentials retrieved via an Amazon Cognito authflow. See [this blog post](http://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/) for additional announcement details.

Comment: Is this still the case? No way to send a verifiable token from the client (JS) to your web-service which can then be turned into credentials?

Comment: @BenSmith Unfortunately, yes. While the Amazon Cognito vended OpenID Connect token can be verified by your backend, this would be simple bearer token security and would not be recommended.

Comment: Oh, how timely! Cheers @BobKinney.